¿Existe una onomatopeya para el sonido de un mono?
Existen muchas onomatopeyas conocidas de animales populares (gato, perro, pato, pájaro, lobo, oveja, gallo, etc.) sin embargo para el mono que es un animal muy conocido y popular, no puedo recordar ninguna, tampoco encontré buscando.
¿Existe una onomatopeya para el sonido de un mono?

-- Jaimito, dime una onomatopeta.  -- Oh ¡no! ¡ma topeya!

La onomatopeya más comúnmente utilizada es "uu uu aa aa" o "uh uh ah ah" que imita los sonidos característicos que hacen los monos.
Esta onomatopeya trata de capturar los gritos y chillidos que son típicos de estos animales.

Así se dice. Una lástima que todavía exista una manga de gente ignorante en este sitio que decidió borrar mi respuesta en la que escribí exactamente lo mismo. @Pablo aceptá la respuesta de una buena vez qué esperás una invitación, papá?

@tac: Completamente de acuerdo contigo.

@tac the problem is that this answer is not a word but a series of sounds (as was your deleted answer)

@mdewey: El verbo utilizado para describir el sonido que hace un burro es rebuznar. La onomatopeya que imita este sonido es "iii-aah" o "iaaa", que intenta capturar el característico bramido de un burro.
El verbo utilizado para describir el sonido que hace un mono es chillar. La onomatopeya que imita este sonido es "uu uu aa aa" o "uh uh ah ah", que intenta capturar los gritos y chillidos característicos de los monos.

@mdewey Exactamente! Una reproducción de los sonidos del mono, de donde extraer la onomatopeya. Qué más se puede pedir?

@tac "Una lástima que todavía exista una manga de gente ignorante en este sitio que decidió borrar mi respuesta en la que escribí exactamente lo mismo".  Fyi, only moderators can remove answers.  You should ping them and ask them why.
